# Filtering ElasticSearch query where date value is lte a given value or missing

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to filter an ES query where the value of a date field is LTE a given value or the field is missing altogether. Here's my query at this point:

```
{
  "from":0,
  "size":50,
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "filter":[
        {
          "term":{
            "corpusid.string.as_is":"42:6:4"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested":{
            "path":"category.object",
            "query":{
              "bool":{
                "must":[
                  {
                    "bool":{
                      "should":[
                        {
                          "range":{
                            "category.object.startdate":{
                              "lte":"2021-03-09T19:32:11.316Z"
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "must_not":[
                            {
                              "exists":{
                                "field":"category.object.startdate"
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When I submit that query, I get the error "[must_not] query malformed, no start_object after query name". We're running ElasticSearch version 5.3.1 in case that matters.

Comment: I think you need another `bool` to wrap `must_not`

Answer (score 1):

I refactored the query a bit. Removed a must, added a bool for the must_not.

```
{
  "from":0,
  "size":50,
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "filter":[
        {
          "term":{
            "corpusid.string.as_is":"42:6:4"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested":{
            "path":"category.object",
            "query":{
              "bool":{
                  "should": [
                        {
                          "range":{
                            "category.object.startdate":{
                              "lte":"2021-03-09T19:32:11.316Z"
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        {
                            "bool": {
                                "must_not": {
                                    "exists": {
                                        "field": "category.object.startdate"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks! I'll give this a go this morning!